# Create new column in database with Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have some database that defined like this:

```
const database = new Sequelize('database', 'user', 'password', {
    host:       'localhost',
    dialect:    'sqlite',
    logging:    false,
    storage:    './database.sqlite',
});

const databaseUsers = database.define('users', {
    userid:         { type: Sequelize.STRING,   unique: true },
    description:    { type: Sequelize.TEXT },
});
```

Then I want to add new value into database. I add new value like this:

```
const databaseUsers = database.define('users', {
    userid:         { type: Sequelize.STRING,   unique: true },
    description:    { type: Sequelize.TEXT },
    money:          { type: Sequelize.INTEGER,  defaultValue: 0,            allowNull: false },
});
```

and it stopping process my commands. I must delete my database and recreate new one with these values.
How should I add new value without deleting my database?

I'm using JS v14.15.4, SQLite3 v4.0.0 and Sequelize modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't adding a new value -- it's creating a new table. You can't have two tables with the same name in the same database.